# Add UITableView to UIView and program crashed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

Is it possible to add UITableView to UIView?
I did the following and my program crashed.

```
     @interface DisplayRecordsViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

     @end

     @implementation DisplayRecordsViewController
    //scroll view
    self.scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(screenRect.size.width*3,screenRect.size.height);
    self.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.564 green:0.439 blue:0.561 alpha:1];
    self.view=self.scrollView;

    self.predictionView = [[PredictionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height)];
    self.predictionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.564 green:0.439 blue:0.561 alpha:1];
    //Add first view view
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.predictionView];


    //Create table view on predictviEW

    // init table view
    int tableViewSize = self.predictionView.frame.size.width/3;
    int x = self.predictionView.frame.size.width/2 - tableViewSize;
    int y = self.predictionView.frame.size.height/2;
    self.heightTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, tableViewSize, tableViewSize) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    // must set delegate & dataSource, otherwise the the table will be empty and not responsive
    self.heightTableView.delegate = self;
    self.heightTableView.dataSource = self;

    self.heightTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];

    // add to canvas
    [self.predictionView addSubview:self.heightTableView];
    [self.predictionView setNeedsDisplay];
    @end


EDIT ERROR LOG:
2015-11-02 22:46:20.694 GrowthAbb[4325:866690] All tables are created
2015-11-02 22:46:40.822 GrowthAbb[4325:866690] -[DisplayRecordsViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12563e3a0
2015-11-02 22:46:40.823 GrowthAbb[4325:866690] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DisplayRecordsViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12563e3a0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1863942d8 0x1980680e4 0x18639b3a4 0x186397f6c 0x18629accc 0x18aee70e0 0x18aee6730 0x18aee6568 0x18aee6374 0x18b10a058 0x18aeec44c 0x18ae08fb8 0x18ae2a97c 0x18ae08cd8 0x18ae08cd8 0x18ae2a97c 0x18ae08370 0x18ae08250 0x18ae14044 0x18aff4ac8 0x18ae08fb8 0x18ae08cd8 0x18ae08370 0x18ae08250 0x18ae14044 0x18aff4334 0x18ae1ab00 0x18aff3ac0 0x18afafb04 0x18aec1e84 0x18aec1c50 0x18aec1bd0 0x18ae096f4 0x18a745db8 0x18a740820 0x18a7406c4 0x18a73fe58 0x18a73fbd8 0x18ae0b688 0x18634c240 0x18634b4e4 0x186349594 0x1862752d4 0x18fccb6fc 0x18ae72f40 0x100120154 0x198712a08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: And why did it crash?  Did you get an exception?  Which line did it crash on?

Comment: It is possible to add all UI elements to UIView as subviews. Let me try to find out what you did wrong. Also provide the error message

Comment: sure you can add a tableview to a view, please show the crash logs and the implementation of the datasource and delegate of the tableview

Comment: Another question: you are adding a subview to a scrollview. Then adding a tableview to the subview. You know tableview is inherited from ScrollView right? Its basically the same essence. Any specific reasons to do so?

Comment: @Avi, I implemented in - (void)viewDidLoad {}. Once out of viewDidLoad, it crashed if I put this line [self.predictionView addSubview:self.heightTableView];. If i don't put this line, it is fine.

Comment: What exactly does it say in the console area? The trace stack?

Comment: Please share the crash log with us!

Comment: @NSNoob, yes because my uiview need some scrolling, so first scrollview, then add uiview to scrollview. then i need to display data in tableview. so i have to add tableview to uiview.

Comment: Try this one  First add tableview in prediction view and than add prediction view in scrollview.

Comment: @FabioBerger, EDIT ERROR LOG: is updated in the original post

Comment: `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` could you share implementation of this delegate?

Comment: @NSNoob, yeah this is error. Thanks

Comment: Thanks all, it works now.